# What's the right way to write to file from Node.js to avoid bottlenecking?

Tags: node.js, optimization, file-io

I'm curious what the correct methodology is to write to a log file from a process that might be called dozens (or maybe even thousands) of times simultaneously.

I have a node process which is called via http and I wish to log from it, but I don't want it to bottleneck as it attempts to open/write/close the same file from all the various simultaneous requests.

I've read that stderr might be the answer to this problem, but am curious what makes that approach any less bottlenecky.  At the end of the day, if stderr is going to some central location, isn't it going to have the exact same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice for node (e.g. http://12factor.net/) is to write to stdout or stderr. The expectation is that the OS will handle the file management / throughput that you want, or else you can have a custom-written log collector that can do it the way you want and redirect stdout or stderr to it.